How to Configure Pylint to Check Similarity Only in Newly Modified Files?
I'm using Pylint to detect code duplication in my Python project. I want to configure Pylint in such a way that it only reports code similarity for newly modified or added files while ignoring the similarity with existing code in the codebase. I need this setup for my CI pipeline to ensure that new code does not introduce unnecessary duplication.
pylint --disable=all --enable=similarities --ignore=migrations,tests apps/
I have used this but it works for whole codebase. Should I add new flags to the above code or should I write a script that includes this code?
